# Sign In Problem Authorization and Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity, user-roles

Hi guys i have 2 question in this topic

Question 1:

I'm trying to sign in but user is coming null when i FindByNameAsync

Registered user's normalizedUserNames is always created null in sql too

im editing in sql normalizedusername then FindByNameAsync found my user but it is problem for me every single register edit.

Question 2:
When i try to login after editing normalizingUserName this time claim is null reference issue.I dont understand where is my problem in codes. Pls help me about this issues and if you have good resources about role based user identity, Authorization and authentication share with me plz.

Create Controller :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AppUser user = new AppUser();
            user.UserName = model.Username;
            user.NormalizedUserName = model.Username.ToLower();
            user.Password = model.Password;
            user.Email = model.Email;


            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            user.NormalizedUserName = user.UserName.ToUpper();
            await userManager.UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(user);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", user.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", item.Description);
                }
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Login Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(LoginViewModel model)
    {

        if (model == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ***Question 1***
            AppUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
            
            if (user != null)
            {
                if(userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password).Result)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignOutAsync();

                     ***Question 2***
                    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, false,false);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", user.Id);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("PasswordWrong", "Password is wrong");
                   return View(model);
                }
             
            }
        }
        model.Password = "";

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account", model);
    }
```

Program cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>, PasswordValidator>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserValidator<AppUser>, UsernameValidator>();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login");
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
             {
                 // Password settings.
                 options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                 options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                 options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                 options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                 options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                 options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                 // Lockout settings.
                 options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                 options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                 options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                 // User settings.
                 options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                 options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;


             })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

             builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
      {
                 // Cookie settings
                 options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                 options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                 
                 options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                 options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                 options.SlidingExpiration = true;
         });


       var app = builder.Build();

       // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
      if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
      {
      app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
      // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production 
      scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
     app.UseHsts();
     }

     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseRouting();

     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
     pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

     app.Run();
```

SQL Snap:
[User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V7E7.jpg)
[UserClaim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74yd1.jpg)

Comment: It is no need set NormalizedUserName  value by using `user.NormalizedUserName = model.Username.ToLower();`.

Comment: But my register is not saved normalizedusername and when i use findbyname no value taking and i get null user